# How to change theme color throught the Toggle in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to change the `theme` color of the App. like my present theme is light but I want to change the theme like Dark Mode with helping the toggle button. 
Some work is doing in my Application. link: https://www.howtogeek.com/361407/how-to-enable-dark-mode-for-youtube/

I build this application but in not working Global, Its only work in the present page like working in the setting page but not working the home page or profile page

I don't have source code but I working this type https://www.seishin.me/dynamic-switching-of-themes-in-react-native-app/

only one-page working but working in the global like working in the setting because I code write code in the setting page, but not working in the profile page or Home Page.

I'm tired...........

Comment: Do you want to change the theme on all screens at once?

Comment: yes, but I change the only color like background-color and font color.

Comment: you can use redux to handle this. take 2 set of constant files where you will have all colors and import those two in each class where ever required and  while setting color check using props.

Ex: <Text style={{color: this.props.colorTheme ==== 'darkTheme' ? darkThemeColors.textColor : lightThemeColor.textColor}}>Hello<Text>

And when ever you are changing the theme store in async that you changed the theme so when u closed the app and open again you can what theme is applied in initial screen and can update your props accordingly.  let me know if more info needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**when you change your theme with your phone**

```
import {View, Appearance} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('LIGHT');
  useEffect(() => {
    const listner = Appearance.addChangeListener(colortheme => {
      console.log(colortheme);
      if (colortheme.colorScheme === 'dark') {
        setTheme('DARK');
      } else {
        setTheme('LIGHT');
      }
    });
    return () => {
      listner;
    };
  }, [isEnabled]);
      
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme === 'LIGHT' ? '#fff' : '#000',
      }}>
    enter code here
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

I've created a single button to change the background color of all the screens. Is this what you want?

[Example link](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/react.createcontext-example) created by me

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { AppContextProvider,AppConsumer } from './AppContextProvider'
import { BlueGray, LightGreen } from './Themes'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <AppContextProvider>
                <MyNavigator />
            </AppContextProvider>);
  }
}


class ScreenComponentOne extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'First screen',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AppConsumer>
          { appConsumer => (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: appConsumer.theme.colors.primary
        }}>
        <Button
          title="Go to two"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteNameTwo')}
        />
        <Button onPress={ () => appConsumer.updateTheme(BlueGray) } title="Blue Gray Theme"></Button>
        <Button onPress={ () => appConsumer.updateTheme(LightGreen) } title="Light Green Theme"></Button>
      </View>
                      )}
            </AppConsumer>
    );
  }
}

class ScreenComponentTwo extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Second screen',
  };

  render() {
    return (
            <AppConsumer>
          { appConsumer => (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: appConsumer.theme.colors.primary
        }}>
        <Button
          title="Go to three"
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteNameThree')
          }
        />
         <Button
          title="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
                            )}
            </AppConsumer>
    );
  }
}

class ScreenComponentThree extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: `Number: ${navigation.getParam('randomNumber')}`,
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AppConsumer>
          { appConsumer => (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: appConsumer.theme.colors.primary
        }}>
        <Button
          title="Add another two"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('RouteNameTwo')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
                            )}
            </AppConsumer>
    );
  }
}

const MyNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    RouteNameOne: ScreenComponentOne,
    RouteNameTwo: ScreenComponentTwo,
    RouteNameThree: ScreenComponentThree,
  },
  {
    // headerTransitionPreset: 'uikit',
    // mode: 'modal',
  }
);
```

**AppContextProvider.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BlueGray, LightGreen } from './Themes'

const Context = React.createContext();

export class AppContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        theme: LightGreen,
        updateTheme: (theme) => {
            this.setState({ theme: theme })
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { theme } = this.state
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={ this.state }  theme={ theme } >
                    { this.props.children }
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export const AppConsumer = Context.Consumer;
export const AppContext = Context;
```

**Themes.js**

```js
import { DefaultTheme } from "react-native-paper";

export const BlueGray = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        primary: '#607d8b'
    }
}

export const LightGreen = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        primary: '#8bc34a'
    }
}
```

Comment: if i don't use `react-native-paper` how can i handle it?