# How to change theme color through a button across App in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I followed this link and implemented theme change using the Context:

[How to change theme color throught the Toggle in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57575157/how-to-change-theme-color-throught-the-toggle-in-react-native)

it's working fine. now want use asyncstorage to store themecolor and retrieve it on App in the foreground/componentWillMount

how do i use appConsumer.updateTheme(BlueGray) in any method outside render or JSX tag?

```
render() {
    return (
      <AppConsumer>
          { appConsumer => (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: appConsumer.theme.colors.primary
        }}>
        <Button
          title="Go to two"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteNameTwo')}
        />
        <Button onPress={ () => appConsumer.updateTheme(BlueGray) } title="Blue Gray Theme"></Button>
        <Button onPress={ () => appConsumer.updateTheme(LightGreen) } title="Light Green Theme"></Button>
      </View>
                      )}
            </AppConsumer>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a functional component you can simply go with the 'useContext' hook and get access to context.

As your requirement is to use componentDidMount you will have to go with a class contextType which will be basically a static variable in your class which points to the context.

The code would be like below, (This is based on the other question link that you have provided)

```
class ScreenComponentOne extends React.Component {
    static context = Context;
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: 'First screen',
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: this.context.theme.colors.primary
                }}>
                <Button
                    title="Go to two"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteNameTwo')}
                />
                <Button onPress={() => this.context.updateTheme(BlueGray)} title="Blue Gray Theme"></Button>
                <Button onPress={() => this.context.updateTheme(LightGreen)} title="Light Green Theme"></Button>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

here `'static context = Context;'` the Context would be the context that you created, it should be exported and imported to this file, but the value would be set based on the component tree.